# Angular 5, Observable to bring back large sets of data

Tags: angular, observable

It seems like "by definition" Observable would be great for loading a table chunks at a time, so you're not waiting on a large number of records before rendering your response -

Can anyone describe how that is done, I've got a company list of 40,000, and a pagination table - but Im always waiting for 40,000 records to load, just to look at the first 100 and page thru them... seems like a common use case. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Your API need to use some techniques to render items per page. You can pass to it the current page, rows in page and server must return correct result based on this logic. Observable just will do the same API request as you have done with 40.000 items, but this time it will pass also some additional data related to the page number and rows in the page.

Comment: I guess I'm confused by the naming of the method ".subscribe", as if there were to be a repeated periodic transmission of data, that one 'subscribes to'. The process you describe (which is what I've ended up using) is just a series of separate api calls, with a set returned. - I don't see how it's different than a promise.

Comment: For just a simple call Observable and Promise will not give you their power. If you want some manipulations with your data, here you can see the power of Observables

Comment: can you point to some examples?

Comment: I think it will be useful for you to read something here - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/sample.html

Comment: Thank you - I'm reading all I can.